# How to amend my tooltip javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

This script fires whenever I'm on a link. I want to change it to fire up when Im on a simple div like: `<div id="personal"></div>` . Thanks for help!

html at the moment:

```
<a href="#" class="fixedTip" title="Hello, I am aToolTip">Fixed Tooltip</a>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){ 
                $('a.normalTip').aToolTip();


                $('a.fixedTip').aToolTip({
                    fixed: true
                });

                $('a.clickTip').aToolTip({
                    clickIt: true,
                    tipContent: 'Hello I am aToolTip with content from the "tipContent" param'
                });     

                $('a.callBackTip').aToolTip({
                    clickIt: true,
                    onShow: function(){alert('I fired OnShow')},
                    onHide: function(){alert('I fired OnHide')}
                });     


            }); 
        </script>
```

main script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.aToolTip = function(options) {
        /**
            setup default settings
        */
        var defaults = {
            // no need to change/override
            closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
            toolTipId: 'aToolTip',
            // ok to override
            fixed: false,
            clickIt: false,
            inSpeed: 200,
            outSpeed: 100,
            tipContent: '',
            toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',
            xOffset: 5,
            yOffset: 5,
            onShow: null,
            onHide: null
        },
        // This makes it so the users custom options overrides the default ones
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            /**
                Decide weather to use a title attr as the tooltip content
            */
            if(obj.attr('title')){
                // set the tooltip content/text to be the obj title attribute
                var tipContent = obj.attr('title');  
            } else {
                // if no title attribute set it to the tipContent option in settings
                var tipContent = settings.tipContent;
            }

            /**
                Build the markup for aToolTip
            */
            var buildaToolTip = function(){
                $('body').append("<div id='"+settings.toolTipId+"' class='"+settings.toolTipClass+"'><p class='aToolTipContent'>"+tipContent+"</p></div>");

                if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId+' p.aToolTipContent')
                    .append("<a id='"+settings.closeTipBtn+"' href='#' alt='close'>close</a>");
                }
            },
            /**
                Position aToolTip
            */
            positionaToolTip = function(){
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                    top: (obj.offset().top - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset) + 'px',
                    left: (obj.offset().left + obj.outerWidth() + settings.xOffset) + 'px'
                })
                .stop().fadeIn(settings.inSpeed, function(){
                    if ($.isFunction(settings.onShow)){
                        settings.onShow(obj);
                    }
                });             
            },
            /**
                Remove aToolTip
            */
            removeaToolTip = function(){
                // Fade out
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).stop().fadeOut(settings.outSpeed, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    if($.isFunction(settings.onHide)){
                        settings.onHide(obj);
                    }
                });             
            };

            /**
                Decide what kind of tooltips to display
            */
            // Regular aToolTip
            if(tipContent && !settings.clickIt){    
                // Activate on hover    
                obj.hover(function(){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                }, function(){ 
                    removeaToolTip();
                }); 
            }           

            // Click activated aToolTip
            if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                // Activate on click    
                obj.click(function(el){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                    // Click to close tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.closeTipBtn).click(function(){
                        removeaToolTip();
                        return false;
                    });      
                    return false;           
                });
            }

            // Follow mouse if enabled
            if(!settings.fixed && !settings.clickIt){
                obj.mousemove(function(el){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                        top: (el.pageY - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset),
                        left: (el.pageX + settings.xOffset)
                    });
                });         
            }           

        }); // END: return this
    };
```

Comment: Surely you can just change `$('a...` to `$('div...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
$('div').aToolTip(); // For any div
$('div#myID').aToolTip(); // For div with id="myID"
$('div.myClass').aToolTip(); // For div with class="myClass"
```